# Filter data in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table, filtering

Im trying to "filter" this data  so the  `[bøde]...`  only gets echo'ed out. And not all the other data.

he data that i want to filter
[image: The data that i want to filter]

how can i do this? i have no idea at all.

Im trying to echo the `[bøde]` in this table:

[image: in this table:]

where the "test" is.

Its the `vrp_user_data` that is the problem, i dont know how to filter it, so its not echo all of the dvalue data

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{

    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    // search in all table columns
    // using concat mysql function
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `vrp_user_identities`, `vrp_user_data` WHERE CONCAT(`user_id`, `firstname`, `name`, `age`, `phone`, `registration` ) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);

}
 else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `vrp_user_identities`, `vrp_user_data` ";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FOLKEREGISTER</title>

    </head>
    <body><center>
        <center><h1>søg i det centrale personregister "CPR"</h1></center>
        <form action="https://mesogames.dk/DDC/FOLKEREGISTER.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="SØG I CPR"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="søg/genlæs"><br><br>


            <table>
                <tr>

                    <th>Fornavn</th>
                    <th>Efternavn</th>
                    <th>Alder</th>
                    <th>CPR</th>
                    <th>Telefon nummer</th>
                    <th>Test</th>
                </tr>

      <!-- populate table from mysql database -->
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>

                    <td><?php echo $row['firstname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['age'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['registration'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['dvalue'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body></center>    
</html>
```

Im not so good at english, so if you want some more info, to help me out feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand what you mean but from what I got correct me if I'm wrong
Are you trying to build a search query?

If so you cannot search from 2 tables  like you are doing there, you have to use inner join for 2 query:

```
$query = "SELECT column-names FROM table-name1 JOIN table-name2 ";
```

Now add you rest of parameters, hope it helps you otherwise let me know I am not this you're looking for.